# cordova 5.0 does not build android

Tags: android, cordova

Few days ago i had updated my phonegap and cordova.

```
phonegap -v
```

5.0.0-0.28.0

```
cordova -v
```

5.0.0

And now I can not make build for android. After I run

```
cordova build android
```

I've got:

```
 error: incompatible types: CordovaWebView cannot be converted to WebView
dbgClient = DebugServiceClient.attachWebView(webView, cordova.getActivity());
```

Does anyone solved same problem ?

My plugins list:

```
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.2.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.5 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.device-motion 0.2.12-dev "Device Motion"
org.apache.cordova.device-orientation 0.3.11-dev "Device Orientation"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.3.0 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.13 "Vibration"
org.jshybugger.cordova 4.5.7 "jsHybugger"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some API is deprecated in Cordova-Android 4.0, that may cause compatibility issue from low-lever plugins, you can try to upgrade them.

Comment: Really it was problem in `org.jshybugger.cordova 4.5.7 "jsHybugger" ` plugin. Thank you! You made my day! :)